# Interactive Ruby CMD opens then closes immediately

Tags: ruby, windows

I installed ruby from the website rubyinstaller.org, then restarted my computer. After reboot I tried opening Interactive Ruby it opens for 1/4 a second and closes and then nothing happens. Is there any reason that would happen?

Comment: What command exactly do you execute?

Comment: No command it just doesn't even open

Comment: I mean, how exactly do you start the prompt?

Comment: oh just search Interactive Ruby in the start menu and I click to open